# Use a list in different functions in python

Tags: python, list, function, global-variables

I want to use a list throughout a program I am writing. Basically, it is a list full of tuples with information regarding different people, each person's information (name, phone, address, etc) is stored as in a tuple. I define this list through an initial function, but i need to use this in my interaction function as well as others.

My question is, is it possible for me to use this list without defining it as a global variable?

```
def load_friends(filename):
    """imports filename as a list of tuples using the import command"""
    import csv
    with open(filename, 'Ur')as filename:
        friends_list = list(tuple(x) for x in csv.reader(filename, delimiter=','))

def add_friend(friend_info, friends_list):
    """appends the friend_info tupple to the list friends_list"""
    new_list = friends_list.append(friends_info)

def interact():
    """interaction function: accepts user input commands"""
    while True:
        command = raw_input('Command: ')
```

I should also mention that there is a command to parse the use inputs to perform the functions. Would this affect the use of the list?

Comment: You can return `friends_list` from `load_friends` and just pass it as a parameter to the other functions, just like you do it in `add_friend`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare `list` inside the first function that calls it and return it from there, latter functions should receive this `list` as an argument then.

```
def func1():
    my_list=[]
    """Do stuff
    """
    return list

def func2(my_list):
    """Do stuff with my_list
    """
    return

def func3(my_list):
    """Do stuff with my_list
    """
    return

def main():
    """First we retrieve the list from func1, 
    func2/3 get it passed to them as an argument
    """
    foo=func1
    func2(foo)
    func3(foo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name, even for an example

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
# you can define the list here, it's global but doesn't require the keyword    
my_list_globally = []

def func1(the_list):
    pass

def func2(the_list):
    pass

def func3(the_list):
    pass

# you can use a hub function to pass the list into things that need it
def main():
    my_list = []
    func1(my_list)
    func2(my_list)
    func3(my_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I don't quite understand the last part of your question but one of those 2 ways will be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Pass the "list of friends" back and forth between functions as an argument.

`load_friends()` would become

```
def load_friends(filename):
    import csv

    with open(filename, 'Ur') as f:
        return map(tuple, csv.reader(f, delimiter=","))
```

`add_friend()` is close, but that assignment to `new_list` is unnecessary, because `list.append()` mutates the existing list in place:

```
def add_friend(friend_info, friend_list):
    friend_list.append(friend_info)
```

would suffice.

`interact()` would also have a `friends_list` argument.

```
def interact(friends_list):
    #interaction stuff here...
```

and you could call it like so:

```
interact(load_friends("myfile.csv"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes are useful for this kind of thing, and easy to use:

```
class PersInfo:

    def setName(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def getName(self):
        return self._name

    def setNumber(self, number):
        self._phNumber = number

    def getNumber(self):
        return self._phNumber

    def setAddr(self, address):
        self._address = address

    def getAddr(self)
        return self._address

def main():
    # Read in data from your CSV Here

    infoList = ([])
    for person in person_list: # Assuming person is a tuple here
        foo = PersInfo()
        foo.setName(person[index1])
        foo.setNumber(person[index2])
        foo.setAddr(person[index3])
        infoList.append(foo)

    # To access the info...
    for person in infoList:
        print(person.getName())
        print(person.getNumber())
        print(person.getAddr())
```

You do end up with the list being "global," sort of.  It is in the `main()` function, where the `PersInfo` objects are being instantiated.  This may be more than you wanted, but in the long run it is a good way to organize your code and keep it readable.

Also, you could build the `infoList` I made directly where you are creating `person_list`.

Comment: What's with all these getters and setters?  This is Python, not Java, as [the man](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html) said.

Comment: Yeah, you're right @DSM.  Are you suggesting better code would just access attributes directly?  Like `foo.name = 'someString'`.